# Chrome Network Devtools capped at 261 requests

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

For some reason, when I open up the Network section on the Chrome Devtools, the requests are are capped at 261. For example, on a page I left up that has a lot of requests, the number at the bottom says 261/8,016. I am looking to view all the files, but I can't figure out how to get past the initial 261. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you have a filter applied.

Comment: Oh. How would I go about removing the filter? In particular, I am interested in viewing .ts files. Only about 100 show up but there should be close to 700.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#filter). I can't help further without seeing what happens in your devtools...